# Load NSView from viewcontrollernib

Tags: objective-c, macos, properties, nsview, nib

So I have a `viewcontroller` `customViewController` that I placed several NSViews on top of using a nib file. I have connected those views to IBOutlet properties in the `CustomViewController.h` file but now I don't know what the next step is to initialize them. What do I do?

Comment: This will be a good read: [Nested Nib Loading](http://blog.yangmeyer.de/blog/2012/07/09/an-update-on-nested-nib-loading). Btw is your question for iOS or OSX? NSViews seems confusing for an iOS guy.

Comment: Link I mention above is for iOS. Not sure if same applies for OSX.

Comment: So is `customViewController` [CIC] (case incorrect) a subclass of `NSViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

Initialized `NSViewController` object   using `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` method.

```
mViewController = [[customViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@“NiBName” bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[mainView setView: [mViewController view]]; //mainView ( [self.window contentView]) in mainMenu.xib
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override **-loadView** method in order to initialize your views.

[NSViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSViewController_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSViewController/loadView)